# Set height and width of an Image

Tags: asp.net, image, height, width

I am using the below code to add Images and I would like to set width and height of an Image.

How do I add to the existing code:

```
 Dim urls As New List(Of String)
 urls.Add("~/DownloadedImages/" & Session("tempDir").ToString & "/" & filename
 For Each imageURL As String In urls
 Me.FinalPreview.Controls.Add(New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image() With {.ImageUrl = imageURL})
 Next imageURL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about VB syntax but the image control has a Height and Width properties that I think will render as the `height` and `width` attributes of the image tag itself. So try passing those the same way you specified the `ImageUrl` property when constructing the control.

Comment: @kprobst-Thanks for your reply and I have tried as you said but it did not worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
     If btnBrowse.HasFile Then
        Dim fileName As String = ""
```

dim imgHeight as integer=25
dim imgWeight as integer=25

```
        fileName = Path.GetRandomFileName.Replace(".", " ") & ".png"
        lblImagePath.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("imgPath").ToString() & fileName
        If File.Exists(Server.MapPath("objectimages") & "/" & btnBrowse.FileName) Then
            File.Delete(Server.MapPath("objectimages") & "/" & btnBrowse.FileName)
        End If
        btnBrowse.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("objectimages") & "/" & btnBrowse.FileName)

        Dim image As Image = image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("objectimages") & "/" & btnBrowse.FileName)
        Dim thumbnailImage As Image = image.GetThumbnailImage(imgHeight , imgWeight , Nothing, IntPtr.Zero)
        '  Response.ContentType = "image/Jpeg/png/jpg"
        'thumbnailImage.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        '  btnBrowse.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("objectimages") & "/" & btnBrowse.FileName)
        Dim bmp As Bitmap = CType(thumbnailImage, Bitmap)

        bmp.Save(Server.MapPath("objectimages") & "/" & fileName)

        bmp.Dispose()



    End If
```